# In terms of generic data structure, how can one efficiently list all the leaves under a node in a tree data structure?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, linked-list

For some time now, I have been wondering and searching for the answer to this question which is :
How can one efficiently (to be specific in terms of time) list all the leaves under a node in a tree data structure ?

I initially thought that it could be done with a linked list that connects all the leafs under that node.

If this was possible then we could iterate through the leaves under a subtree in linear time of O(n) where n is the number of leaves under that subtree.

But, it sounds impractical considering that each subtree will need to have different linked list.

So, I would be thankful if someone can point if it is possible or if it is not and why ?

Let us consider a simple binary tree in this case.

Regards

Comment: Hi Yochai, I have edited the text now to make it clear. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The [B+ Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B+_tree) allows pointer (next, prev) between leafs. Assuming all your data is stored at the leaf level then a B+ tree may be the best way to accomplish what your asking.

[image]

If you are asking, only leafs nodes which have a common root node (not the root of the entire tree), you can just find the left most node under that root and keep following the "next" link until you hit a leaf node whos value is greater than the right node of your root node.

Answer (score 0):

It's not impractical at all.

You for each leaf you could set the "next" leaf, and then in each node only store a pointer to the first (or smallest) leaf, and last leaf (biggest leaf)

Then you can get to the first leaf from each node (subtree) and iterate over the leafs.

The first and last leafs can be updated on insertion with an O(logn) complexity.

Answer (score 0):

well in a generic tree that has no special features (each node has just payload index and pointers to subtree) you'll have to walk the whole subtree there is no other way at least for the first time

than if you need to access those leaves node again with a fast method you could set up a vector/array of pointers that gives you almost O(1) time access but you'll have to manage the pointers so that when you insert new nodes you don't reference old leaves any more but new ones

if you need leaves corresponding to multiple subtrees a simple and fast solution could be a multidimensional array (2D in this case) under normal circumstances but it could be a problem if you have really big datasets or limited memory (in this case you could want to swap to B+Tree that's more memory friendly for your needs)

Answer (score 0):

Speed and memory size is always a trade off.

There are hundreds of different tries in science.
But all such additional pointers or list etc. need additional memory.
And thats not practical for a generic solution, when the speed problem is in most cases
not the tree.
If you need a very special tree, for a specific application that want to list all leafes below a tree node, than you would have to use a specialized implementation, when you want something faster than simply iterating the left and right subtree, which I consider as reasonable fast.

And further who wants to know the leaves of all subnodes?
This an internal topic of the tree, from outside you even **should not know** what is below a node. (Think of balanced trees, the change their struction).